# Sonarcube :Null pointers should not be dereferenced

Tags: spring-mvc, sonarqube

lets say  DefaultMessageSourceResolvable is spring framework class  and the method `getCode()` may return `null`

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DefaultMessageSourceResolvable implements MessageSourceResolvable, Serializable {

    @Nullable
    private final String[] codes;

    @Nullable
    public String getCode() {
        return (this.codes != null && this.codes.length > 0 ? this.codes[this.codes.length - 1] : null);
    }

}
```

Using the `getCode()` method in another class
Sonar Lint gives error:

> A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getCode()" can return null.

```
//inside this test class we are checking the condition what the getCode() method return 
//and then performing some task 
class Test {

    DefaultMessageSourceResolvable error = new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable();

    if (error.getCode().contains("something"))
    //error.getCode() this may return null so sonar gives 
    //major  issue
    {
        //do something 
    }

}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for a null reference before you use the `String#contains` method.

```
class Test {

    DefaultMessageSourceResolvable error = new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable();

    // Java with no third party libraries
    String errorCode = error.getCode();
    if (errorCode != null && errorCode.contains("something"))
    {
        //do something 
    }

    // Java using the very popular "org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils" library
    if (StringUtils.contains(error.getCode(), "something"))
    {
        //do something 
    }
}
```